# Is it safe to remove all user passwords except root?

Tags: linux, users, password

Is it safe to remove all passwords (`passwd -d`) from users, including service users like apache, bind, and others, and keep only the root password? I suspect that a malicious user may have set a password on one of these users pass later access.

Comment: Yes but but who knows what damage has been done or if that will help.

Comment: I a malicious user has set the password on a service account, does that mean you believe you've been hacked? How do you know that the machine is not fully compromised and/or that there are no keyloggers and rootkits installed?

Answer (score 0):

*safe* is somewhat subjective.  I would say no, a better approach would be

- `passwd -l <account_name>` to **lock** the account,
- verify all service accounts, like apache, bind, are also locked and that they have a *non-login* or *non-interactive* shell such `/bin/false` or `bin/true`, [ or `/bin/nologin` if available on your system ] ... *sorry, I forget exactly what the current shell types are but basic point is for service type accounts that do not need an interactive/login shell make sure they do not have one; they should not have `/bin/bash`*
- monitor your log files and audit logs and watch for any kind of red flag

`passwd -Sa` is quite useful showing all accounts, if they are locked

Answer (score -1):

Much safer to just delete the users altogether. If you want them to be there but inaccessible, just set their home directory to `/dev/null`, and they will log in and automatically be logged out